# AS3 Error #1009 in my constructor?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, null

So I'm working on a 2d platforming game, and I'm getting a #1009.

In my Pickup() class, in the constructor, I'm trying to set this.x and this.y to the center stage, but it's saying the stage a null object reference.

```
public function Pickup() {
        // constructor code
        bitmapData.draw(_displayObject);    
        mSprite = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
        addChild(mSprite);
        this.x = 
        stage.width/2;
}
```

I separated the this.x and the stage.width to see which part was triggering the null, and it's definitely the stage.

It's probably something so horribly obvious I'm going to beat myself up for not noticing it.

Anyways, any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: How did you separate  the `this.x` and the `stage.width`?

Comment: I just hit Enter to see put them on separate lines to see which line triggered the error, which I am now seeing is actually the stage.width which is calling the error. Question changed.

Comment: Wait for the added to stage event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stage` property is `null` on any DisplayObject, unless it is actually on the Stage.

This means you'll need to add an event listener to the object listening for [`Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED_TO_STAGE), and then work with the `stage` in the handler.

Alternatively, you could just pass a reference to the Stage to the constructor of Pickup:

```
public function Pickup(stage:Stage)
{
    // Your code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener of  add to stage

```
public function Pickup() {
   // constructor code
   bitmapData.draw(_displayObject);
   mSprite = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
   addChild(mSprite);
   this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);
 }

protected function onAddToStage(event:Event):void
{
     this.x = stage.width/2;
}
```